# Secondary hard drive 100% usage

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I recently installed SSD into my laptop and moved the old HDD to DVD drive. I did a clean install of windows 10 onto SSD. Now my HDD in unusable: the system can see it, but I can't do more than view a few folders and then it stalls: it doesn't calculate space, Disk Management freezes upon start, I cannot even disable that drive via Device Manager (although I can do it if I do not try to touch that drive after boot). Of course, chkdsk doesn't do anything.

This is how Task Manager looks currently: constant 50% disk usage.
[image: Task manager 1]

Another view of Task Manager:
[image]

Why does Windows 10 behave that way? Can I do anything about it?

Comment: Can you check the Device Manager for any driver conflicts?

Comment: @MusselmanLLC Yes, it looks normal. While I do not try to access the disk in any way, I can enable/disable it in Device Manager with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be resolved, but I haven't identified exactly which of the three following actions has helped:

1. I replaced Windows 10 bundled WLAN driver with the one I downloaded from laptop vendor's website. I don't know how that could be connected, but HDD sometimes worked normally after that. (Before, it was 100% reproducible freeze upon first access).
2. I switched Optibay adapter into diagnostic-pin-blocked mode (there's a switch, I moved to left position). After that, about 50% of boots were followed by HDD normal operation.
3. I changed "Link power management mode - HIPM/DIPM" setting to Active in Power Management. Now, HDD works.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the same symptoms, and resolved it by unplugging the hard drive's SATA cable and reconnecting it.